# Java syntax confusion

Tags: java

Given two strings,write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other. Below is the model solution. I don't understand this statement: `if(--letters[c]<0) {return false;}`

Why not just write `if(letters[c]==0){return false;}`
 Can someone please clarify.

```
 public boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
        if(s.length()!=t.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        int[] letters = new int[256];

        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        for(char c : s_array){
            letters[c]++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<t.length(); i++) {
            int c = (int) t.charAt(i);
            if(--letters[c]<0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `**` since that doesn't apply the formatting you wanted inside of the ` ticks.

Comment: --letters[c] is nothing but , pre decrement.

Comment: @SimonT Why?  The question is still clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea is to make sure that the number of each letter that's in `s` is equal to the number of each letter that's in `t`.  You do this by counting up how many of each letter is in `s`, then counting down again, for each time each letter occurs in `t`.  The `letters` array does this - each entry in the array represents one character that might occur, any number of times, in each of `s` and `t`.

For example, if `s` is `"AABC"` and `t` is `"BCAA"`, then after the first `for` loop, the `letters` array will contain 2 for element A, 1 for element B and 1 for element C.  After the second `for` loop, these have all been decremented back down to 0.

Since you've already checked that `s` and `t` have the same length, if they're not made up of exactly the same letters, there will be SOME letter that occurs more times in `t` than in `s`.  When you get to that letter, decrementing the corresponding value in letters will result in a negative count, so you return false.

Conversely, if `s` and `t` have exactly the same letters, there is no letter that occurs more times in `t` than in `s`, so you never get to the line that says `return false;` - so you end up returning `true`.

Comment: Perfect Explanation. if(letters[c]==0){return false;} will only work in the case where the characters are different in string S and string T.

Answer (score -1):

This statement means

```
if(--letters[c] < 0) {
  return false;
}
```

That the compiler would first decrement the value of the index and get it from array. Then it would check for the value with the condition. If `true` then return false.

It would be `true` if the value is a negative integer (less than zero). Maybe the code developer, wanted to check for the value, if its less than zero. You should note, that the index value of the Array starts at 0. And if you do this

```
System.out.print(letter[0]);
```

You will get a result. To check if there is no value or for other particular function. Developer first decreased the value, with the decrement operator and then he checked for the condition.

`--variable` is known as pre decrement.

Where as the second code block means something else.

```
if(letters[c]==0){
   return false;
}
```

It would execute only and only if the value of Array at the index `c` is equal to 0. All of the other possible conditons would be rejected and the block won't execute.

Comment: That doesn't explain why this is in the program.

Comment: But why is the code doing that? Why not just check for if(letters[c]==0){return false;}

Comment: Because they're different. If he checks it at `0`, it would be true always because index numbers start at 0. He is trying to decrement it to convert it to `-1` so that code gets true only if there is a trouble with the Array.

Comment: lol why? letter[c] has nothing to do with the index, but only with the value, on position c!

Comment: So for that you downvoted it? @conFusl .. actually, we get the value using the index number. For that we use `letter[c]`.